# How to handle identity for asp.net forms authentication calling backend service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication, wif

Considering the following scenario:

I have an MVC web application written in asp.net 4.5 that is using forms authentication.

For authenticating the current user, I am calling a web service method which tells me if the login is valid and if it is I am setting the identity on the web application after getting the response from the web service.

My problem now is that I want to be able to identify the user in both the MVC web application as well as on the back-end services when the user places the calls, would prefer doing this from configuration if possible.

Another concern is where should I create the session token and do session management? Don't want my authentication method being called on every single request, so I suppose I need a session token caching mechanism and also don't want to set the credentials for the proxy on every request, if possible I want this to be done from configuration, is it possible using WIF and if so how?

What would be considered a good approach on implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

The approach I decided to use is the following:

- Use OWIN cookie authentication (no modules, just using the middleware)
- Decided there is no point for now to use any web services, got rid of an extra physical layer, this should bring better performance
- For storing the authentication tickets, I implement the IAuthenticationSessionStore interface

Example:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
      SessionStore = new MyAuthenticationSessionStore()
   });
}
```

On the Login method I do something like the following:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Brock"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "brockallen@gmail.com"));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

And to get the current user with its claims I can do the following:

```
OwinContext ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
ClaimsPrincipal user = ctx.Authentication.User;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;
```

Some references that might be helpful:

[Owin cookie authentication middleware for asp.net](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/)

[Owin protocol middleware cookies and session](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/05/11/owin-protocol-middleware-cookies-and-reference-mode-sessions-we-need-your-feedback/)

[Leastprivilege blog](http://leastprivilege.com/)

[brockallen.com](http://brockallen.com/)